# Does File.delete() delete the pointer of the File object?

Tags: java, file, java-io

My co-workers and I are having an argument about how the `File.delete()` method works in Java.

In our code:

```
File outFile = new File("/dir/name.ext");
if(outFile.exists())
    outFile.delete();

FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(outFile);

WriteFile.writeFile(inStream); // Writes the actual file
```

I can't include the entire method body of `writeFile` here for security reasons, but after it creates the database object needed, it performs the following action:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = null;

Object[] args = {"an_encrypted_data_clob_name_in_the_database"};
Class[] argTypes = {Class.forName("java.lang.String")};
Object result = WSCallHelper.jdbcCall(null, rs, "getCLOB", args, argTypes);
CLOB clob = (CLOB)result;
out = new BufferedOutputStream(clob.getAsciiOutputStream());

byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int bytesRead = -1;

while((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > -1)
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

I know it's a little unclear, but the general gist of it is that it creates an `AsciiOutputStream` of the `Clob` (yes it's supposed to be a `Clob`) and writes it to the `inStream` object that is passed from the previous method.

They're convinced that this won't write to the file directory because of the `File.delete();` method, but I know for a fact that there was a file in that location yesterday, and this code ran today and wrote a file in that exact location. Because, although the actual *file* is deleted, the *pointer* for where that file is located is still in `outFile`, and the creation of `inStream` with `outFile` makes `inStream` point to that location.

Is there any reason to believe that this file wouldn't be written in this scenario?  Ideally, I'd like some proof that the `delete()` method removes a file that the `File` object *points* to, not the pointer itself.

Comment: Can't you just try it?

Comment: Strange - writing to a File**Input**Stream?

Comment: A `File` only contains a file location; it doesn't maintain any sort of connection to the file, and won't keep a file alive.

Comment: I'd like to see complete code - including the posted statements - that does write the file.

Comment: @laune I've included the statement as best I can - though due to security reasons, I can't include the SQL call that initially uploads the CLOB itself.

Comment: @forgivenson I have.  It created the file just as I expected.  I'm trying to convince my co-workers that it will work every time, but they're still confused by how the File.delete() method works.

Comment: What about reading the Javadoc of File.delete() to them if they can't read it for themselves? I don't see much leeway for misunderstanding what's written there.

Comment: Ditto what @AasmundEldhuset said.  `File` is a poorly named class because a `File` instance does _not_ represent (or in any way stand for) a file.  A `File` instance represents a _pathname_.  It should be obvious that deleting a file with a given pathname does not prevent you from subsequently creating a new file that has the same pathname.

Comment: @laune Having read it, I can see how they might get confused by it - Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted - if they don't understand that the File object acts as a pointer to that directory, and that it *still* acts as a pointer even after invoking this delete method, they might think we're losing the pointer when invoking delete.

Comment: Why should File.delete() be any different that the equivalent function in a file browser, or the cmd interpreter, or the shell, where you call /bin/rm?

Comment: @laune I'm not sure.  They seem convinced *now*, only after several minutes of confirming that it does in fact work that way, so maybe all I'm really looking for is proof that it does in fact run in that manner at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is not a file pointer, nor does it hold a file pointer. It is an immutable pathname.

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.
>
> Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system object such as a file or a directory.
>
> Instances of the `File` class are immutable; that is, once created, the abstract pathname represented by a `File` object will never change.

With [the source code for `File`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java?av=f), we can see it is a wrapper around a `String`.

[`delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) cannot remove a file pointer because there is no file pointer.

> Deletes the file or directory **denoted by this abstract pathname**.

Connections to open files are represented by [`java.io.FileDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html):

> Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file […].

This is how input/output streams interact with the file system, not through `File`, for example [`FileOutputStream(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-) explains the following:

> Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified `File` object. **A new `FileDescriptor` object is created to represent this file connection.**
>
> If the file […] does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

And we can observe that, for example, [the constructor for `FileOutputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#FileOutputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%2Cboolean%29) that is delegated to merely gets the path `String` from the `File`, checks if it's valid, then discards the `File`:

```
public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
    throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkWrite(name);
    }
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (file.isInvalid()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid file path");
    }
    this.fd = new FileDescriptor();
    fd.attach(this);
    this.append = append;
    open(name, append);
}
```

There's no documentation to support the idea that `java.io.File` represents a file pointer. ; )

We also know that an open handle to a file is a resource that must be released at some point, but `File` does not provide a means to do so; ergo, `File` does not fit our notion of what a file pointer should be.